# Laravel 5.8 Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException: The given data was invalid

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-unit-test

I have store method in my controller like this

```
public function store()
{
     request()->validate(['family'=>'required']);
     User::create(request()->all());
     return redirect('/users');
}
```

and test method like this

```
/** @test */
public function a_user_require_family()
{
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
    $this->post('/users', [])->assertSessionHasErrors('family');
}
```

It show me this:

> 1) Tests\Feature\UserTest::a_user_require_family
>   Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException: The given data was invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `assertSessionHasErrors('family')` which catches a `ValidationException` on the key `family` only if the key was passed in the request body and then failed your validation.

But in your case you are not passing the said key at all (You send an empty body `[]`).

You need to use `assertSessionMissing()` in this case.

**Try:**

```
$this->post('/users', [])->assertSessionMissing('family');
```

**Laravel Documentation** : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/http-tests#assert-session-missing

Answer (score 7):

You cannot use `$this->withoutExceptionHandling()` and also `->assertSessionHasErrors('family')` because all Validation errors are Exceptions which get handled by `Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException` which you are expressly forbidding to run.

Simply remove `$this->withoutExceptionHandling()` and your test should pass.

Comment: I comment `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();` but show me same error